# CakePHP - Is 2.5.3 still worth learning?

Tags: cakephp

This question is aimed at active CakePHP enthusiasts and users. There has been 3.0 beta1 release recently, and I am wondering is it still worth my time to begin learning 2.5.3 CakePHP book, or it is better to jump into 3.0 version instead, and learn it in the phase as it currently is (beta1) ?

It is all about the learning curve, since I would like to avoid situation when I didnt finish to learn current framework version and 3.0 is on the run, because as far as I see the releases are released quite frequenty.

Any advice you can give me ? I am on the crossroads at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jump straight into 3.0, without a doubt.

3.0 will be a little trickier to learn as there'll just be more resources availabile for 2.X - however, 3.0 introduces some really big changes, particularly in the model layer. So if you do learn 2.X, a lot of what you learn will have to be un-learned once you move into 3.0.

I'd start with the 3.0 blog tutorial: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

In general, since tech moves so fast and becomes outdated so quickly as it is, IMO you'd need to have a very good reason to learn a previous version when a new major version is just about to be released.

Comment: I will do this then, I saw that CakePHP is moving forward in a rapid fashion... Thanks for making me choose the way.

Comment: Keep in mind that CakePHP 3.x has dropped backwards compatibility for PHP versions bellow 5.4.19. This is something you need to know if your smaller projects are going to be hosted on cheap shared hosting.